# How to change link's logo in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i wanna change a link in logo header in wordpress, but i don't know how to change that, i've try to change *header.php* , unfortunately, that's not working

*header.php*

```
<?php
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="body-content-wrapper">

        <header id="header-main-fixed">

            <div id="header-content-wrapper">

                <div id="header-top">
                    <div id="weglot_here"></div>
                    <? //php fart_display_social_sites(); ?>
                </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                <div id="header-logo">
                    <?php fart_show_website_logo_image_and_title(); ?>
                </div><!-- #header-logo -->

                <nav id="navmain">

                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                              'fallback_cb'    => 'wp_page_menu',

                                              ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #navmain -->



                <div class="clear">

                </div><!-- .clear -->

            </div><!-- #header-content-wrapper -->

        </header><!-- #header-main-fixed -->

        <div id="header-spacer">
            &nbsp;
        </div><!-- #header-spacer -->
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: First you have to print this `fart_show_website_logo_image_and_title()` function here.

Comment: Have you tried finding where that function is? Or just write an a tag to overwrite the current href

Comment: thanks , i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the **fart_show_website_logo_image_and_title()** function inside [functions.php](https://github.com/tishonator/fart/blob/master/functions.php) and change the href attribute in the line below to the one you want:

```
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url('/') ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name') ) . '">';
```